# Passing parameters when using ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ds_ShippingServiceProfiles" runat="server"   
     SelectMethod="GetCardStatusValues"
     TypeName="AccountsDataHelper">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

public static DataTable GetShippingProfiles(long storeID)
{

}
```

I can get the `storeID` like this : `new websiteDatahelper().SelectedStoreID.Value`

how can i send the storeID parameter when using `ObjectDataSource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a handler for the `OnSelecting` event:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ds_ShippingServiceProfiles" runat="server"   
     SelectMethod="GetShippingProfiles"
     TypeName="AccountsDataHelper"
     OnSelecting="ds_ShippingServiceProfiles_Selecting">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Implement the event:

```
protected void ds_ShippingServiceProfiles_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
     e.InputParameters["storeID"] = new websiteDatahelper().SelectedStoreID.Value;
}
```